# Select Top 1 with ties with distinct on another field column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table record like this:

```
AutoID  ReceiptNo  Outlet_Code  
-------------------------------- 
    1       SUN12        Store X     
    3       SUN12        Store X     
    4       ART123       Store y
```

I would like to select a top 1 with ties based on Outlet_Code with Distinct on the ReceiptNo such that in this case, my result will be:

**Store X / Store Y**

because I should read the 2 Store X records as 1 as they have the same receiptNo.

This is a portion of my query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES (Outlet_Code)                  
From [Trans] T                 
WHERE T.CardNo IN (Select [CardNo] From [Card]                
                         Where  [MemberID] = 
                         (Select [ID] From [Member]  Where [autoid] = @MemAutoID ))   
GROUP BY Outlet_Code     
ORDER BY Count(T.Outlet_Code) Desc
```

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: What's wrong with the query you already have?  Does it give the wrong result?  Does it give an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Ewww... Subqueries... Would this work for you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Outlet_Code  
FROM [Trans] T, [Card] C, [Member] M
WHERE T.CardNo = C.CardNo
AND C.MemberID = M.ID
AND M.autoid = @MemAutoID
ORDER BY Count(T.Outlet_Code) Desc
```

Or the less lazy way...

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Outlet_Code  
FROM [Trans] AS T
JOIN  [Card] AS C ON (T.CardNo = C.CardNo)
JOIN [Member] AS M ON (C.MemberID = M.ID)
WHERE M.autoid = @MemAutoID
ORDER BY Count(T.Outlet_Code) Desc
```

Comment: Ewww... implicit joins from 1987? Strongly recommend sticking to proper `INNER JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand you correctly but how about using `DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Outlet_Code FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY clause correct, but in the ORDER BY clause must use a distinct column value ReceiptNo

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Outlet_Code                  
FROM [Trans] T                 
WHERE T.CardNo IN (
                   SELECT c.[CardNo]
                   FROM [Card] c JOIN [Member] m ON c.[MemberID] = m.ID                
                   WHERE m.[autoid] = @MemAutoID                   
                   )
GROUP BY T.Outlet_Code     
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT T.ReceiptNo) DESC
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a5e8/1)